# ORA-00920 when running query through UI Framework

Tags: oracle, plsql

My company works with a UI Framework written in PLSQL which interacts with a Java client program.
A lot of queries need to be passed as a VARCHAR2 string to it to be called when needed.

The query

```
SELECT DISTINCT cod_visum 
FROM tbl_visum 
WHERE      num_firma = 0 
      AND (code_visum BETWEEN 1 AND 799 OR code_visum BETWEEN 900 AND 999) 
      AND id_worker IS NULL 
      OR ( date_valid_to IS NOT NULL 
           AND p_date_from > NVL (date_valid_to, p_date_from + 1)) 
ORDER BY 1;
```

runs fine and returns the expected results when run from the TOAD editor, but when I pass it as a VARCHAR2 to the framework, I keep getting an ORA-00920 (Invalid relational operator) but can't find the cause. (Also the framework catches the exception and only shows me a dialog with the exception number and text >.<)

I've tried several methods of concatinating the variable *p_date_from* into the VARCHAR2, like

```
v_sql_norm   VARCHAR2 (450)
     :=    'SELECT DISTINCT code_visum 
            FROM tbl_visum 
            WHERE        num_firma = 0 
            AND (code_visum BETWEEN 1 AND 799 OR code_visum BETWEEN 900 AND 999) 
            AND id_worker IS NULL 
            OR (    date_valid_to IS NOT NULL AND '
        || p_date_from
        || ' > NVL(date_valid_to , '
        || (p_date_from + 1)
        || ')) ORDER BY 1';
```

I already checked the date formats, tried to convert the dates to a string before concatination but everything results in the same exception.
The table used in the query looks like this:

```
+--------------------+-------+-------------------+
|    Column Name     | NULL? |     DATA TYPE     |
+--------------------+-------+-------------------+
| ID_VISUM_ASSIGMENT | N     | NUMBER (12)       |
| NUM_FIRMA          | N     | NUMBER (3)        |
| CODE_VISUM         | N     | VARCHAR2 (3 Char) |
| ID_WORKER          | Y     | NUMBER (10)       |
| DATE_VALID_FROM    | Y     | DATE              |
| DATE_VALID_TO      | Y     | DATE              |
+--------------------+-------+-------------------+
```

Side info: a visum (or visa?) is assigned to a worker starting at a specific date (date_valid_from). It can be assigned to a certain date (date_valid_to), or indefinitely assigned (date_valid_to is NULL).

Thank you in advance, really appreciate any help! :)

edit: yes, cod_visum is a VARCHAR2 but in the query it's used as NUMBER but I also already tried casting it to a number (and mostly it's casted explicitely ^^)

Comment: What is the definition of the procedure and how do you call it?

Comment: The definition is: `PROCEDURE setVisumBox (p_isVP_visum IN BOOLEAN, p_date_from IN DATE)`. The boolean indicates the value range from which code_visum is picked from.

Answer (score 1):

This bit is wrong: the fourth line mixes variable with boilerplate.

```
        OR (    date_valid_to IS NOT NULL AND '
    || p_date_from
    || ' > NVL(date_valid_to , '
    || (p_date_from + 1)
```

It should be something like

```
        OR (    date_valid_to IS NOT NULL AND '
    || p_date_from
    || ' > NVL(date_valid_to , ('
    || p_date_from
    || ' + 1)'
```

Also the logic seems wonky, but that's an aside.

Comment: Yes, the logic is pretty messed up, but that's because I have to work with a system grown over decades with dozens of strange restrictions... :D Unfortunately this didn't resolve the error, still getting the same exception